# Send SMS. Отправка sms в android 8

Tags: android, sms

на android 6 смс получается отправить, но на 8 версии не работает, возможно на 7 версии тоже не работает, не тестировал.
Кто знает, в чем проблема, может эту возможнасть в 8 версии урезали для безопасности и тд?

разрешение при установке на отправку смс подтверждаю, окно разрешения имеется.
Использую этот код

```
 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
 smsManager.sendTextMessage(numbe, null, smsBod, null, null);
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 0):

Для отправки sms можно использовать `intent`:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:"));
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "your message");

if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
       sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");           

context.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Да, через него пробовал, но он всего лишь открывает смс приложение с введенным номером. . Я использую смс как сигнал о том что сервер упал. Нужно автоматически,  Возможно ли отправить автоматически ?

Comment: можно про сервер поподробнее? мне просто кажется что смску отправлять о том что сервер упал как-то не очень логично)

Comment: Да там ничего интересного, просто приложение проверяет сайт работает или нет, если не работает отправит оповещение

Comment: лучше тогда уже письмо на почту слать либо через firebase сделать, но через смску делать как-то не очень хорошо, потому что если например у пользователя нет денег на счету а сайт лежит то он вам ничего не отправит и там еще куча таких если будет)

Comment: Возможно отправить смс без участия человека в 8 версии?

Comment: без участия очень сомневаюсь, google вообще сейчас довольно жестко начали запреты на приложения у которых есть доступ к такого рода службам

Comment: хм, жаль, попробую по вашему тогда, спасибо